# How come a nullable column does not take null value on insert statement?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I currently have a table that has a `null` column, but when performing an insert statement, the MySQL database throws an error that says `#1048 - Column 'admi_name' cannot be null`.

Here is the table query:

```
    drop table if exists `tbl__users`;

    create table `tbl__users`(
    `user_email` varchar(256) not null,
    `user_last_name` varchar(256) not null,
    ...
    `user_bank_iban` varchar(32) not null,
    `admi_name` varchar(128) null,  -- Admin that approved the account
    constraint PK__USERS primary key (`user_email`),
    constraint FK__USERS__ADMINS foreign key (`admi_name`) references `tbl__admins` (`admi_name`)
    );
```

Performing an insert statement where `admi_name` is null throws an error, is there something wrong with what I did? This did not happen before as I was able to insert values where `admi_name` was null but then suddenly MySQL says this is wrong.

Also, I know the column data types are wrong, nevermind that right now.

I came across this problem when I called a stored procedure that has an insert statement. Since the error was pointing to the insert statement, I tried the query

```
    insert into `tbl__users` (`user_email`,
    `user_last_name`,
    ...,
    `admi_name`) values ('john@doe.com', 'Doe', ... , null);
```

The query still throws the error `#1048 - Column 'admi_name' cannot be null`. Still have no clue on what the error is.

A strange thing I encountered is that if I place a valid value on `admi_name` then perform an update query changing the `admi_name` column to `null`, the query goes through without any errors. I also tried to replicate the issue on simpler table designs without any luck.

Comment: `admi_name` on table `tbl__admins` can't be `NULL`?

Comment: Yes. A nullable column that doesn't take `null` as an input
Edit: the table is `tbl__users`

Comment: Why can't be null? I don't understand your question.

Comment: And the issue can't happen on trying to insert a row to `tbl__admins`?

Comment: @MacGyver The question is how come I cannot insert `null` into a column that is supposed to allow `null` as a value. The reason why `null` is supposed to be in that column is because if the account is not yet approved by an admin, then there is supposed to be a `null` admin account. Once the user is approved, only then can an admin account be in that column

Comment: I hope you have the full secure and valid certification for holding banking transaction details at rest ?

Comment: @SebastianBrosch No. I am trying to insert a row on `tbl__users`. I already have values on `tbl__admins`

Comment: @Martin I didn't design the schema, only followed what the guy paying me told me what the schema is supposed to look like. I told about the security of saving banking details too, I'm not sure what goes on his mind, though

Comment: I suggest you to edit your question and put that comment you told me, it's clarify a lot the question. We need your help to help you :) Show your attemps, maybe the problem is in the way you do it.

Comment: can't reproduce the issue at the moment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0288a7f69a07191bfa556c21c38ce2bd

Comment: @SebastianBrosch I'm also trying to reproduce this issue on a simpler table design. I can't seem to either